# Winter Release 23 was installed in my org and now I am unable to insert Opportunities via Apex

Tags: apex, financial-services-cloud, winter23

I am getting the following error:
System Code)
17:05:53.175 (1986907158)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Can only throw this exception type from VisualForce or Aura context

It appears to be coming from the FinServ.OpportunityTrigger

Answer (score 4):

This [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002Lmp3QAC) related to Financial Service Cloud and Winter '23 (which I presume you meant in your question) is the same thing. That known issue mentions `FinServ.TaskTrigger`, but the same stacktrace. If the workaround listed in that KI does not work, I'd recommend putting in a support case to understand how to work around it until it is fixed/patched.

The workaround is listed as such:

> - Create new field set on AccountContactRelationship.
> - Add some fields into the field set
> - The following field sets are required. (Names must be matched)
>
> "Group_Members"
>
> - "Relationships_with_other_Groups"
> - "Relationships_with_other_Accounts"

Comment: That did resolve my issue.  However, it's not clear to me exactly how the proposed solution solved the issue or what exactly the issue was.  Anything else you can add as I am concerned that I might have broke something else by adding the solution to my code base.

Comment: Creating field sets won't impact your code base. This is to assist with FSC's code base's issue which I would expect to be patched. I believe the existence of these field sets prevents their code from entering the fault path. I would recommend looking back at the known issue as the workaround has been updated with more details (fields to add to field set).